# pagination not working with new php function via ajax

Tags: laravel-5.7, laravel-pagination

I am fetching records via ajax with search parameters and want to have pagination also. It works fine if I use it with the same function which loads view, for example

```
  function viewOrder(Request $request){
   $data = products::where('categoryId', 1)->paginate(1);

    if ($request->ajax()){
      return view('store.showAjax')->with('data',$data);
    }
      return view('store.show')->with('data',$data);
  }
```

But my need is like this

```
  function viewOrder(){
      return view('store.show');
  }

  function searchOrder(Request $request){
      $data = products::where('categoryId', 1)->paginate(1);
      return view('store.show')->with('data',$data);
  }
```

In this way It creates pagination but when I click on page link it load store.show view twice in the same html page. How can I achieve correct pagination this way? 
Doing everything in viewOrder() function looks messy.

Answer (score 0):

I just find out how to do it, simply passing full url instead passing `?page=1` in javascript function `

```
 function getData(url, page){
    $.ajax({
        url: url, //'?page=1',
        type: "get",
        datatype: "html",
        success: function(data){
          $("#tag_container").empty().html(data);
          location.hash = page;
        }
    });
}`
```